# Reducing values array of objects to an array without duplicates using Set

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, set

I have following array of object:

```
[{
    "user": {
      "tags": [{
        "tag": "T1"
      },{
        "tag": "T2"
      }]
    }
  }, 
  {
    "user": {
      "tags": [{
        "tag": "T2"
      }]
    }
  }, {
    "user": {
      "tags": [{
        "tag": "T3"
      }]
    }
  }]
```

And need to collect all the tags with no duplicates as below using **ES6 Set**

**["T1","T2","T3"]**

Can any one help me?

Comment: Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Side note: Although you *can* use `reduce` for this, it doesn't buy you anything, it just adds complication. Just use nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments. Here's a nested loop implementation,

```
const data = [{
    "user": {
      "tags": [{
        "tag": "T1"
      },{
        "tag": "T2"
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "tags": [{
        "tag": "T2"
      }]
    }
  }, {
    "user": {
      "tags": [{
        "tag": "T3"
      }]
    }
  }];

const tagsSet = new Set([]);

data.forEach(val => {
  val.user.tags.forEach(t => {
    if(!tagsSet.has(t.tag)){
      tagsSet.add(t.tag);
    }
  });
});

console.log(tagsSet); // Set(3) {"T1", "T2", "T3"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer using **reduce** and **Set**. Thanks T.J.Crowder !

```js
const data = [{
    "user": {
      "tags": [{
        "tag": "T1"
      },{
        "tag": "T2"
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "tags": [{
        "tag": "T2"
      }]
    }
  }, {
    "user": {
      "tags": [{
        "tag": "T3"
      }]
    }
  }];
  
  let uniqueTags = []
   const allTags = data.reduce((current , next) => {
        current.user.tags.push(...next.user.tags);
        return current;
      });
      uniqueTags = [... new Set(allTags.user.tags.map(t => t.tag))];
      console.log(uniqueTags);
```